# jQuery Cycle Plugin : white background in IE (any version)

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, background, transparency, cycle-plugin

in IE jQuery Cycle Plugin sets the background to white... even i have the CSS transparent for everything

Comment: Which part gets the white background? The container? Please provide jsfiddle if possible

Comment: no only the slideshow\viewer part.. http://wallz.moon.pk/home.php check out the backgrounds of thumbnails

Comment: It's working fine in IE 9, but on IE 8, it does get white background. I'm looking at it, and will update if I get time.

Comment: The white background is there to keep the transition smooth in ie.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the correct answer to the original question:

Add this param to your jQuery:
cleartypeNoBg:true

so it should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your_div_id').cycle({       
        fx: 'fade',
        cleartypeNoBg:true
    });
});
```

-W

Answer (score 0):

If your css has rgba values and still it is not being displayed then you should try add this to your ie.css file for that particular div

Transparent background for IE hack :

```
background: transparent; 
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#808ED557,endColorstr=#808ED557);
```